# How to generate random characters without repeating?

Tags: java, random

I want the function to generate random characters from A-Z without repeating if it's called again. For example, i called it in my main first and it generates an A character. If i called it the second time, it shouldn't generate A again. How to do it?

```
public static void random(){
    Random r = new Random();
    char c = (char)(r.nextInt(26) + 'A');
    System.out.print(c);
}
```

If this helps, what i'm planning is to put it on a hashmap as a key and it shouldn't have the same characters.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you have a small fixed limit, it is more economical to generate the whole random sequence upfront, and then take it one character at a time:

```
List<Character> sequence = new ArrayList<>();
for (char c = 'A' ; c <= 'Z' ; c++) {
    sequence.add(c);
}
Collections.shuffle(sequence);
for (Character c : sequence) {
    System.out.print(c);
}
```

The method above creates a `sequence` of all letters `A` through `Z`, and then applies [random shuffle](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#shuffle(java.util.List)) to it ([demo](http://ideone.com/30fupq)).

The sequence that you get back is in random order. You can take items from it without fear that they are going to repeat.

Answer (score 1):

i think you can use a list like this peice of code,

```
public static void main(String args[]) {
    List<Character> listChar = new ArrayList<>();
    //put all your character in this list
    for (int i = 0; i <= 26; i++) {
        char c = (char) (i + 'A');
        listChar.add(c);
    }
    Random r = new Random();
    int id = r.nextInt(listChar.size());
    char c = (char) (id + 'A');
    System.out.print(c);
    listChar.remove(id); 
}
```

I hope this can give you and idea

Comment: I made a condition and it works but i think that works too. Thank you!

Comment: you are welcom Meryel

Answer (score 0):

I managed to fix it. I'll keep this forum up if anyone is wondering how. It's in a hashmap so i just put a condition of `hashmap.containsKey()`

```
    Random r = new Random();
    char c = (char)(r.nextInt(26) + 'A');
    if(hm.containsKey(c)){
        c = (char)(r.nextInt(26) + 'A');
        hm.put(c, newValue);
    }
    else
        hm.put(c, newValue);
```

Comment: Your fix is broken. It will very likely produce duplicates.

Comment: The reason why this would happen is that there is no guarantee that your random generator wouldn't produce two collisions in a row. Your code assumes that the second `r.nextInt(26)` wouldn't collide, but it is not true. Consider a hash map with 25 of 26 positions filled. The probability of hitting the unfilled spot is very low, so the chance that the second call wouldn't give you a unique spot is very high.

Comment: @dasblinkenlight you are right! thank you for informing me. I tried your fix and it definitely works. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I think the most proper way to do it, just use the following construction with [SecureRandom](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/security/SecureRandom.html):

```
// define valid symbols for random string 
private static final String ALLOWED_CHARACTERS = "0123456789ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz";
// generate the string
public String randomString(int len) {
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(len);
    for (int i = 0; i < len; i++) {
        sb.append(ALLOWED_CHARACTERS.charAt(secureRandom.nextInt(ALLOWED_CHARACTERS.length())));
    }
    return sb.toString();
}
```

Comment: How exactly does this solve the problem of not repeating results? This limits the character set, but that was not what OP asked.